# Travel to Austria for few days and then re-enter in France with French 'Recepisse de Demande de Carte de Sejour"

Tags: schengen, france, austria

I need to go to Austria to attend a conference. I am not a European and my French visa is expired. Can I travel to Austria for few days and then re-enter in France ?

According to this source:https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1765?lang=en . It seems like I can do this, but I need to be sure.

Edit1: My Récépissé clearly states " A demande le renouvellement de son titre de sejour ...". So I guess it is not the "premiere demande".

Edit2: I do have an expired "Titre de sejour".

Edit3: Document of concern looks like this: https://ibb.co/tB4vDmp

Comment: Why do you believe that a '*residence permit application receipt*' is equivalent to a residence permit? For the question **To travel within the Schengen area**, you should answer *You do not have a residence permit*, since you only have a **application receipt** for a residence permit.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Good point, so basically I came upon some posts which mentioned that if one has "premiere demande" of "titre de sejour" then one can't travel inside the Schengen area, but if one is renewing the "titre de sejour", in this case the récépissé as good as "titre de sejour" , it allows to circulate in Schengen area.

Comment: With the 'apply for the renewal of their residence permit' statement it may be very well possible to travel with the expired "Titre de sejour". It is, I believe, only for *first time* applications, that travel is not possible.

Comment: Do you have an expired French "titre de sejour" document?

Comment: Please add a clear statement in your question that your are renewing an existing residence permit that has now expired. Did it expire after the receipt was issued?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Yes I do have an expired "titre de sejour"

Comment: @MarkJohnson So first my "titre de sejour" expired and then I got my récépissé.

Comment: Here: https://www.bouches-du-rhone.gouv.fr/layout/set/print/Demarches-administratives/Etrangers/Foire-aux-questions-Etrangers . The question 28 does answer that it should be ok to travel if the récépissé is for renewing/modification. But I couldn't find anything on  the official site www.service-public.fr

Comment: The Schengen Border Code Article 2 (Definitions) 16(b) only excludes first time applications (*temporary permits issued pending examination of a **first application** for a residence permit*...). So the renewal receipt togeather with the previous (expired) "Titre de sejour" should be ok.

Comment: What’s the date at the end of the last sentence of the _Récépissé_? (“_dont les effets sont prolongés jusqu’au …_”)?

Comment: @jcaron Good question, the récépissé will expire by next the mid of June. However, I will travel in mid July, so either I suppose that I will get my renewed carte de sejour or a new récépissé, right ?

Comment: @amitoz you are probably giving a bit too much credit to French bureaucracy… at the very least I wouldn’t expect them to deliver the récépissé automatically, you’ll probably have to request a new one if you haven’t received your new titre de séjour by then (though I’m not really familiar with those procedures do I may be wrong). And of course there’s the possibility they decide bot to renew it (again, not familiar with the procedures and the chances of it happening).

Comment: @amitoz from the French perspective, the récépissé should be equivalent to the titre de séjour until the given date. I suppose they intend it to be the same for other countries, but I have no idea if they will take it at face value/recognise it.

Answer (score -2):

I'd say technically speaking, you're already illegal there, unless the law covers you while a renewal is being processed (which is the case in many countries with residency permits).  That would then go to whether or not you received the receipt for request before the expiration date, and local law.

In practicality, you're traveling within the borderless zone, and unless you do something stupid, have very, very little risk of being questioned over the legality of your presence.  Outside of special circumstances (checking the news might be one way to do this), checking documents at borders within the Schengen area is prohibited by EU law.  So, again, unless you run afoul of the law for some other reason, you shouldn't be asked for your documents barring extreme circumstances (I recently traveled to Switzerland from France, and read about additional checks because of the riots in France, but in reality there were no checks, and the customs office wasn't even open for basic declarations, as Switzerland is in Schengen, but outside EU - so sometimes even standard, basic checks aren't carried out for whatever reason within Schengen).

Point is, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: No need for rude suggestions at the end of the answer.